# Email & Password validation not working in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying below code for email/password validation but form is not submitting after successful validation.
Any help ?.

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = $(".email").val();
  const password = $(".password").val();
  const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  console.log(re.test(String(email).toLowerCase()));
  $('.email_v').text('');
  $('.pass_v').text('');
  if (!re.test(String(email).toLowerCase())) {
    $('.email_v').text("Please provide Valid Email Address");
    return false;
  }
  if (password.length < 6) {
    $('.pass_v').text("Password must be atleast 6 characters");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` prevents the form from submitting.

Comment: Why do you use `toLowerCase()` when the regexp matches both upper and lower case? And it's not necessary to call `String()`, since `.val()` always returns a string.

Comment: Move the line `e.preventDefault()` to the places returning `false` or don't do any returns and use `e.preventDefault` if validation fails at the end of your callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.preventDefault()` called at the beginning of the script stops the form from being sent.

See the docs:

> The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur. For example, this can be useful when: Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form. Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

You may move `preventDefault` to the places where validation fails, as suggested.

Comment: There are much better [documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) than W3Schools, please use those instead.